# Find all verses that contain a word or phrase in the bible in sub-linear time?

Tags: swift

I was planning on using a dictionary as my data structure where the keys equal all the words found in the bible and the values store an array of integers where each integer points to an index of a verses array. My implementation looks something like this:

```
let verses = [String]() //All verses in the bible
var dict = [String:[Int]]() //Data Structure

func fillDict(){
    for verseIndex in 0..<verses.count{
        let words = verses[verseIndex].componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for word in words{
            if let indexArray = dict[word]{
                var newIndexArray = indexArray
                newIndexArray.append(verseIndex)
                dict[word] = newIndexArray
            }else{
                let arr = [verseIndex]
                dict[word] = arr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Filling the dict is obviously very slow. I am looking for either a faster implementation or a different data structure that will guarantee sub-linear search time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, you only need to build your data structure once.  Then you can save your dictionary on disk, build it as part of your app, and load it directly from the file.  (Or you can do the same thing with a pre-loaded database if you need fancier searching.)

Comment: That is what I was originally intending on doing. My main complaint is in the time it takes to fill the dictionary. I was hoping I could avoid it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**TL; DR:** Swift's arrays are copy-on-write. Avoid the copying by using `NSMutableArray`.

---

Swift's array are value types. To append a new element to an array of length 9, it needs to allocate an array of capacity 10, copies the first 9 over, and assigns the new element to the last slot. This of course takes a lot of cycles. To demonstrate, let's slightly revise your code and run it through Instruments to get an idea of what's taking so long:

```
let bible = try String(contentsOfFile: "King James Bible.txt")
let verses = bible.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(.newlineCharacterSet())

func fillDict1() -> [String: [Int]] {
    var dict = [String: [Int]]()

    for verseIndex in 0..<verses.count{
        let words = verses[verseIndex].componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for word in words{
            if let indexArray = dict[word]{
                var newIndexArray = indexArray
                newIndexArray.append(verseIndex)
                dict[word] = newIndexArray
            } else {
                let arr = [verseIndex]
                dict[word] = arr
            }
        }
    }

    return dict
}

fillDict1()
```

(I used the King James Bible available at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/10). I know the `verses` array doesn't have the right verse break-down but that's irrelevant to the question at hand.)

Select **Product > Profile** (`Cmd + I`) then choose the Time Profiler. Here's the top 3 most expensive calls:

```
Running Time        Self (ms)   Symbol Name
6464.0ms   61.8%    5.0         specialized Array._copyToNewBuffer(Int) -> ()
1093.0ms   10.4%    6.0         String.componentsSeparatedByString(String) -> [String]
896.0ms    8.5%     0.0         specialized _VariantDictionaryStorage.updateValue(B, forKey : A) -> B?
...
(Total: 9736ms)
```

As expected, allocating new memory to new arrays take a lot of time. Fortunately, Apple has already solved this problem for you in `NSMutableArray`:

```
func fillDict2() -> [String: [Int]] {
    var tmp = [String: NSMutableArray]()

    for (verseIndex, verse) in verses.enumerate() {
        let words = verse.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for word in words {
            let indexArray = tmp[word] ?? NSMutableArray()
            indexArray.addObject(verseIndex)

            tmp[word] = indexArray
        }
    }

    var dict = [String: [Int]]()
    for (word, verses) in tmp {
        dict[word] = ((verses as NSArray) as! [Int])
    }

    return dict
}
```

Run `fillDict2()` through Instruments again and here's what I got:

```
Running Time        Self (ms)   Symbol Name
916.0ms   21.5%     8.0         String.componentsSeparatedByString(String) -> [String]
783.0ms   18.4%     27.0        specialized _VariantDictionaryStorage.nativeUpdateValue(B, forKey : A) -> B?
754.0ms   17.7%     0.0         specialized _VariantDictionaryStorage.updateValue(B, forKey : A) -> B?
...
(Total: 3911ms)
```

2.5x faster! Obviously you can look for other optimizations as well. It's a never-ending game. You have to determine when it's fast enough for you.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! I will work to see if I can optimize a little more ;)